# TypeScript-'s Angular Framework Error - "There is no directive with exportAs set to ngForm"

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular2-forms

I keep getting this error while using TypeScript's Angular2-forms framework:

> *There is no `directive` with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"*

Here's my code

project dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "0.6.17",
    "jquery": "3.0.0",
  }
```

And this is the Login Template :

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ng-submit)="authenticate(loginForm.value)">
</form>
```

...and  the Login Component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers}  from '@angular/http';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'login-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor($http: Http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }
  authenticate(data) {
   ... 
  }
}
```

I have this Error :

```
zone.js?1474211973422:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:    
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("
            <form [ERROR ->]#loginForm="ngForm" 
(ngsubmit)="authenticate(loginForm.value)">
```

Answer (score 585, accepted):

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
             BrowserModule,

             FormsModule      //<----------make sure you have added this.
           ],
  ....
})
```

Comment: I've done this and I still get the error. Any other ideas? (I'm on the release version.)

Comment: Make sure you have added relevant package and referenced it in systemjs.config.js.

Comment: It *must* be bound to <form> element

Comment: @pop Thanks, was adding it to `div` and it caused this error.

Comment: Thanks, I keep forgetting this goes in the `imports` array, and not the `providers` array

Comment: my problem solved with add ReactiveFormsModule in my module.

Comment: <form #employeeForm="ngForm" class="emp-form" write properties you want it >

Comment: This fixed an error I had running unit tests against a template with the #v="ngForm" directive.

Comment: please also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959037/angular-5-no-provider-for-controlcontainer because I had same issue despite of this module but after adding ReactiveFormsModule problem solved.

Comment: @All - Can we used both `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` at a time ?

Comment: also if you are using VScode, restarting VScode is a good idea, it looks like sometimes VScode it self freaks out and keep giving the same error even after fixing all the typos and importing your modules.

Comment: If you're working with NgbCollapse, make sure to add `[(ngbCollapse)]="isCollapsed"` to the reference element.

Comment: Make sure your component in the declarations in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 69):

You have to import `FormsModule` into not only the root AppModule, **but also into every subModule** that uses any angular forms directives.

```
// SubModule A

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule      //<----------make sure you have added this.
  ],
  ....
})
```

Comment: You can add to export array, then you'll not need to add it to multiple submodules imports

Comment: @SamihA Please explain with example, the export array goes in AppModule or Submodule A?

Comment: Also don't forget to import ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: Worked for me - but I found it didn't clear the error until I killed npm and reran npm run start.

Answer (score 58):

I have added `ReactiveFormsModule` in `imports[]` array to resolve this error.

Error: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("

**Fix:**

module.ts:

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule , 
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks, Got resolved after adding "ReactiveFormsModule"....

Comment: Also be aware that component that uses this directives is declared(in declaration property of NgModule) besides FormsModule import

Answer (score 18):

```ts
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule],
  ...
})
```

Comment: I've done this and I still get the error. Any other ideas? (I'm on the release version.)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same error and I have FormsModule imported as well.

Answer (score 16):

(Just in case someone else is blind like me)
`form` **FTW**! Make sure to use `<form>` tag

wont work:

```
<div (ngSubmit)="search()" #f="ngForm" class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Go!</button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" ngModel class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search...">
</div>
```

works like a charm:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="search()" #f="ngForm" class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Go!</button>
     </span>
     <input type="text" ngModel class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search...">
</form>
```

Answer (score 10):

In case a name is assigned like this:

```
#editForm="testForm"
```

... the exportAs has to be defined in the component decorator:

```
selector: 'test-form',
templateUrl: './test-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test-form.component.scss'],
exportAs: 'testForm'
```

Answer (score 10):

This

```
<div #myForm="ngForm"></div>
```

Also causes the error and can be fixed by including the [ngForm directive](https://angular.io/guide/forms#the-ngform-directive).

```
<div ngForm #myForm="ngForm"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Another item check:

Make sure you component is added to the declarations array of @NgModule in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    YourComponent,
],
```

When running the `ng generate component` command, it does not automatilly add it to app.module.

Answer (score 7):

check whether you import FormsModule. There's no ngControl in the new forms angular 2 release version. you have to change your template  to  as an example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-7 col-md-5">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required
               [(ngModel)]="user.name"
               name="name" #name="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
            Name is required
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Three Things you have to care:

1. If you're using the sub-module, you have to import the `FormModule` in that sub module:

   ```
   imports:[CommonModule, HttpModule, FormsModule]
   ```
2. You have to exports the `FormModule` in the module:

   ```
   exports:[FormsModule]
   ```

   so together it looks like:

   ```
   imports:[CommonModule, HttpModule, FormsModule],
   exports:[FormsModule],
   ```
3. In the top of the file you have to import the `FormsModule`:

   ```
   import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
   ```

---

If you are using only the `app.module.ts` then no need to export. Only import required.

Comment: If you use FormsModule within your own module you need the following in your xxxx.modules.ts.  
Import Forms from Angular:
    `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`  

Add it to the imports array NgModule:  
    `@NgModule({    imports: [               FormsModule    ],`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to import the form module in login component ts file you need to import NgForm also.

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

This resolved my issue

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'NgForm' imported by the module

Comment: Did you _do anything_ with `NgForm`??? Add it to declarations?

Comment: Yes, after adding it is visible in browser..Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've come to this same question over & over again, also due to same reason. So let me answer this by saying what wrong I was doing. Might be helpful for someone.

I was creating component via `angular-cli` by command

> **ng g c** components/something/something

What it did, was created the component as I wanted.

Also, While creating the component, it **added the component in the App Module's declarations array**.

If this is the case, please remove it.
And Voila! It might work.

Answer (score 3):

If you already import `FormsModule`, then you just need to remove `formControlName='whatever'` from the input fields.

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }from'@angular/forms';

imports:[
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule/*This one in particular*/,...
],
```

in app.module.ts to permanently solve errors like `"cannot bind [formGroup] or no directive with export as"`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes i faced same problem...I did above all things but not worked.
This one solved my problem. Because we are using angular 'with' in strict mode.

in app.module.ts add this code

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule
],
```

and which file you are using NgForm
in .html file

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginSubmit(form);">
</form>
```

and in .ts file

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss']
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  NgForm=NgForm;//this one solve my problem...initialization and declaration
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs if you are trying to write a unit test case in angular using jasmine.

The basic concept of this error is to `import FormsModule`. Thus, in the file for unit tests, we add imports Section and place FormsModule in that file under

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule
    For eg: 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ XYZComponent ],
        **imports: [FormsModule]**,
    }).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to add my component in the Declaration array of app.module.ts, and voila! the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the answers talk about adding the `FormsModule` module but in my case the import is already done. As said in an answer to the question, you have to close and restart VScode or in my case you have to save your workspace with "Save workspace as ..." and everything will work normally again.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Very good but this also did not work. error is there. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have already imported and added the `FormsModule` to the  Sub Module that you are going to use, and **still facing the error**,

**1. You may missed it to add the  root AppModule. (silly but it happens sometimes)**
**2. Make sure you have added relevant package and referenced it in systemjs.config.js**

Answer (score 2):

In your **app.module.ts**

Make sure,

1. **FormsModule** in **imports**
2. **SampleComponent** in **declarations**

Answer (score 1):

You must declare FormsModule and must declare also the Compoponent

```
declarations: [
   YourComponent  -->
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, -->

    
  ],
```

Comment: This was the case for me. I add FormsModule but did not add my component in the AppModule and it was giving me error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should terminate app with ctrl+c and re run it with ng serve, if you  did not include FormsModule into you app.module file imports array, and then added it later, angular does not know it, it does not re-scan modules, you should restart app so angular could see that new module is included, after what it will included all features of template drive approach

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the `ngNoForm` attribute from my `<form>` tag.

> If you you want to import FormsModule in your application but want to skip a specific form, you can use the ngNoForm directive which will prevent ngForm from being added to the form

Reference: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-ngform-ngnoform-template-reference-variable/

Answer (score 0):

I just moved routing modules i.e. say ARoutingModule above FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule and after CommonModule in imports array of modules.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the solution provided by @micronyks but that hold's true if you've simple application which doesn't have many modules within it. Otherwise, we need to add in similar way to module where we're using that <form #loginForm="ngForm"> element and adding below code inside that module if you don't want to expose it to all modules or whole application.

```
import FormsModule from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule{
imports: [FormsModule],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> .HTML file <form (ngSubmit)="addIngredients(f)" #f="ngForm">
>
> .ts file @ViewChild('f', { static: false }) slForm: NgForm;

**in HTML updated ngForm to NgForm worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **FormsModule** module was missing from imports. Upon adding this mine started working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using directive. make sure you add `exportAs: 'something'` with `selector`

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me (Angular 16.2.7) but this did. Change the HTML element in the template from this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" >
```

To either this:

```
<form #myForm ngForm >
```

Or this:

```
<form myForm="ngForm" >
```

These are from [this GitHub post](https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-8/issues/157) about the issue.