# Angular2 - Form Directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I've just started working in Angular2. Right now, i'm facing issue when add form directive to Form. I've following html form. For sake of simplicity, i'm just putting over here the necessary fields. I've named my component **Category**. 
Following is **Category Model**

```
export class Category {
    Title: string;    
    Description: string;

    constructor(Title: string, Description: string) {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Description = Description;
    }   
}
```

Following is **category.template** file

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="model.Title" #title="ngModel" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="model.Description" #description="ngModel" class="summernote form-control" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </div>

</form>
```

Following is **category.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { Category } from '../../../models/cms/Category';

@Component({
    selector: 'category',
    templateUrl: 'category.template.html'
})
export class CategoryComponent{

    model = new Category("dummyTitle","dummyDescription");

    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }   
}
```

And this is the error that i get.

```
Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("


    <form [ERROR ->]#form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
```

Please help me how to resolve this error.

Comment: You need to import `FormsModule` in the module where your component is declared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559296/there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngform)