# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

Got the below error when I try to test `LoginComponent`

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 55 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.307 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) LoginComponent should create FAILED
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("iv class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">
          <form (ngSubmit)="login(f)" [ERROR ->]#f="ngForm">
            <div class="card card-login">
              <div class="card-header text-cen"): LoginComponent@5:38
```

A part my component looks like,

`login.component.ts`

```
export class LoginComponent {

  isBusy: boolean = false;
  user: User;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private sessionService: SessionService,
  ) { }
  ....
}
```

And the corresponding spec looks like,

`login.component.spec.ts`

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let routerStub = new RouterStub();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      declarations: [,
        LoginComponent
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
          return new Http(backend, options);
        },
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
      },
      { provide: Router, useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); } },
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        AuthenticationService,
        SessionService,
        NotificationService
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

seems like it fails to create a fake component using the above providers, declarations, etc. Like [other's said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39559318/3297613), I already included `FormsModule` inside `@NgModule` decorator.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure what `@NgModule` decorator you added it to but I think it should be added in

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule, FormsModule],
```

Comment: I want to dynamically add an attribute to an element.. So I tried like .. `<input type="{{input.type}}" name="{{input.name}}" class="form-control" [attr.disabled]="input.disabled" value="{{input.value}}">` but it genrated `<input .. disable="true">` but I want `<input disable>` based on the boolean value of `input.disabled`

Comment: You can't create just `disabled` using Angular2 binding, but `disabled` and `disabled="true"` shouldn't matter. To remove it you need `null`, because `false` will result to `disabled="false"` which is similar to `disabled`. `[attr.disabled]="input.disabled ? true : null"` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks this answer helped.

Comment: Thanks Man, just for the super stupid fellas like me, you do need to add the FormsModule on top of the file by

`import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: @superjisan yes, everything needs to be imported, so I didn't add this explicitly. I assumed that the IDE suggests to add imports anyway, but it probably depends on the IDE.

Comment: I had to import ReactiveFormsModule.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I solved it by importing FormsModule in BOTH app.module.ts AND the sub-module the component sits on, which in my case was core.module.ts.

I was following the Angular style guide and put the login component in the core module, so the folder structure for my login component was:   app/src/core/login/login.component.ts

I did not need to import ReactiveFormsModule as some others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The answer masked as accepted is currently outdated, as *HttpModule* is currently deprecated. An alternative could be using *HttpClientTestingModule* instead:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, FormsModule],
```