# Angular 5: "No provider for ControlContainer"

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a little web app with Angular 5 and out of a sudden I am getting this strange error message in my browser console:

```
ncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("
</p>
<form class="container" (ngSubmit)="update()">
  [ERROR ->]<app-form-group-component 
[formGroup]="additionalInformation"></app-form-group-component>
      <button "): ng:///AppModule/KickoffComponent.html@4:2
```

That did not happen before and I am not aware of any made changes. And I have no idea what that message tries to tell me.

This is the component template of form-group which seems to be invalid somehow:

```
<div *ngFor='let e of formGroup' class="form-group">
<label for="{{e.key}}">{{e.label}}</label>
<input type="{{e.type}}" name="{{e.key}}" 
[(ngModel)]="e.value" class="form-control" 
[ngClass]='{"is-valid": e.valid === true && e.required === true}'
        />
    </div>
```

And this is the template where I consume form-group:

```
<form class="container" (ngSubmit)="update()">
 <app-form-group-component [formGroup]="additionalInformation"></app-form-group-component>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<app-notification [notification]="notification"></app-notification>
```

I stared at it for hours, but I can't find any mistake.

I should mention that I don't use Angular's FormGroup but my own solution (because I thought theirs to be overengineered and it didn't fit my specific needs). Could there be some kind of name collision? Of course, in the app.module I have imported the FormsModule for two-way binding to work and to intercept the form's submit.
The notification-component at least works without complaints.

I would be very grateful for any help.

**Edit:**
I was asked to share my TS code.

Failing component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '../../models/form-group';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-group-component',
  templateUrl: './form-group.component.html',
})
export class FormGroupComponent {
  @Input() formGroup?: FormGroup
}
```

The type *FormGroup* is just an Array and the component is just meant to be a visual wrapper.
There are no additional services involved or DI and without that component Angular compiles just fine.
(*formGroup* is marked as optional because TS would keep complaining about it not being initialized, although at runtime it will always be initialized)

Component which hands over property:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { additionalInformation } from "./additional-information";
import { basicInformation } from "./basic-information";
...

@Component({
  selector: "app-kickoff",
  templateUrl: "./kickoff.component.html",
})
export class KickoffComponent implements OnInit {
  basicInformation: FormGroup = basicInformation;
  additionalInformation: FormGroup = additionalInformation;
  methods...
}
```

**Edit:** To answer @Andrei's question: I have no service or provider called ControlContainer. I just have three small services, none of them causes any trouble. As far as I can tell, ControlContainer has something to do with DI, but Angular's documentation on that topic is rather mystifying.

Comment: Can you share your ts code?

Comment: I'm afraid there is too little here to make much sense of the issue. Angular is complaining about someone requesting a provider (service)  with the type ControlContainer that cannot be found in any injector. Is that a service that you've defined? Where is it injected? what module is it part of?  Is it declared as a provider there?

Comment: I think naming your input the same thing as an angular forms directive is a bad idea in general, even if it doesn't cause a conflict.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The `ControlContainer` is a abstract class which is extended by the `AbstractFormGroupDirective` inside the `ReactiveFormsModule`.

The error is thrown if you're using the `ReactiveFormsModule` and a `<form>`-element without a `FormGroup` bound to it via `[formGroup]="myForm"`.

To fix this error you have to create a `FormGroup` and bind it to your form:

```
<form class="container" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="update()">
```

> Also make sure you have both the `FormsModule` and the `ReactiveFormsModule` added to your module imports.

Comment: Chage myForm by basicInformation and additionalInformation  inside the component '<filename>.ts' with:

basicInformation = new FormGroup = basicInformation;

Comment: Event if I do that, the error persists. So, I added _ReactiveFormsModule_ and _FormsModule_  to the component's module import, and it works.

Answer (score 110):

For Me its turns out that i imported just ReactiveFormsModule but not FormsModule.
you need to import both.

Comment: I had the same. Even if you want to use a form element purely for display purposes, you have to import FormsModule if you have ReactiveFormsModule imported.

Comment: Same solution for me here with Ionic 4 Angular 8 ;)

Comment: Year 2020 here, had to import both forms modules and re-serve the app to get this error to be clear.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out that the error had nothing to do with `form` not being bound to a `formGroup`, but me naming the receiving variable also `formGroup`. That confuses the heck out of Angular.

Just renaming this variable solves the issue.
That is okay now:

```
<form class="container" (ngSubmit)="update()">
 <app-form-group [fg]="additionalInformation"></app-form-group>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This has helped me, thanks. Had a similar situation with an ngb-bootstrap NgbDialog variable that was named (too simply) 'dialog'. This was apparently confusing Angular 11.0.4 (used to work with at least some of the previous versions). Giving the variable a better name fixed the problem. Style matters!

Answer (score 7):

This issue happen when you import `ReactiveFormsModule` and missing `FormsModule` in the module. So we need to import it to the module that your component belong to

```js
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class XXXModule { }
```

Comment: The two modules `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` are separate and not dependant on one another. Importing FormsModule may stop the error but wouldn't actually fix the mistake in the code.

Comment: @JonCatmull if u look at the code. He is using both Reactive Form and Template Driven Form in template. So, Import both module will fix the issue.

Comment: This worked! You have to restart the server for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is still having this error while using the Angular CLI, i was only importing the `ReactiveFormsModule`, then i imported and registered the `FormsModule` to fix the error. I was serving the app with `ng serve` when i made changes to the module class and i was still having the error even after importing and registered the `FormsModule`. To fix the error i had to stop serving and start again in order to recompile the module class.

Answer (score 3):

if did not registering your component in your app module, then it means you have to  import the ReactiveFormsModule in that component's module.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this with two changes.

**1)** I had my component in its own module. I had to import THAT specific module into the app.module. That got me half way to the solution.

**2)** I also had some fields whose values were generated in the component and being displayed in the form group. Once I took those out of the form group and put them in a separate div, then I was set to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is still having issues with this. I ran into the same error. However, it was not related importing ReactiveFormsModule or FormsModule .

In my case, I had copied a component directory from a different directory, and my SCSS imports in the ~.component.scss were relative to the initial directory that I copied from.

The error did not suggest this was the case and it took a little too long to finally consider checking other component files. Dur!

Answer (score 1):

For me (and for those creating a **TAB** application), it turns out I had to add the imports for FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in the **tab1.module.ts**.  I have found no other answer for this type of senario so I thought I would share it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I encounter this error I make the mistake of using reactive forms and using an input named `@Input formGroup` in one of my own components.

### Error: Using reserved word for @Input

#### Component

```ts
@Input()
formGroup: FormGroup;
```

#### Using it

```html
<!-- Angular now thinks this is a form which causes the error -->
<my-own-component [formGroup]="formGroup"></my-own-component>
```

### Solution 1: Use other word for @Input

#### Component

```ts
@Input()
form: FormGroup;
```

#### Using it

```html
<!-- This works -->
<my-own-component [form]="formGroup"></my-own-component>
```

### Solution 2: Alias the input

#### Component

```ts
@Input("form")
formGroup: FormGroup;
```

#### Using it

```html
<!-- This works too -->
<my-own-component [form]="formGroup"></my-own-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue with Angular 9. Only solution that helped is removing `@Host ()` from the dependency declaration in the constructor. Angular new Rendering engine [Ivy doesn't like `@Host()` decorator](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31539).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the solution here, but at the end I had to add

```
viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
```

to the `@Component` annotation, so my Typescript class looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './my-app.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-app.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]
})
export class MyAppComponent {
```

Answer (score 0):

So for me it ended up being because I had put 'ReactiveFormsModule' in the exports section in one of my top level modules.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow bootstrap class was conflicting with angular.

I had to remove the top level div with bootstrap class.