# Angular Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]

Tags: angular, mean-stack, mean

> core.js:5873 ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]

Sometimes when I restart the project it runs perfectly.
There are only changes in app.component.html :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form action="">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it's late, but someone will help with this comment. Stop running project and rebuild everything will work if dependency will correct

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In `app.module.ts` I add `ReactiveFormsModule` in my `imports` section. Remember to import it at the top as: `import {  ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms`.

In your `app.component.ts` you have to define `FormGroup` instance and initialize/register it via `ngOnInit` method as below:

```
    import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'; //imports
.......................................................................
    myForm:FormGroup;  
    ngOnInit(){
         this.myForm = new FormGroup({          
               'name':new FormControl(null), //note, can have up to 3 Constructor Params: default value, validators, AsyncValidators
               'email':new FormControl(null,Validators.email)

          })
    }
```

Then bind form to the `FormGroup` instance `myForm`:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
```

Note that `name` and `email` are controls in the form that needs binding using `formControlName` :

```
<input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
```

Comment: It may be helpful to note that importing of FormGroup MUST come before FormControl or you will continue to see this error.

Answer (score 14):

you have to import both,
 `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` into your corresponding module.ts file. that worked for me.

Comment: For anyone else who bumps into this, I not only had to add `import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';` to `app.module.ts` I also had to add it to the ts file for my form.

Comment: One has to decide whether to use app.module.ts, app.component.ts and app.component.html to setup the form OR to use files representing a smaller scope like  signup.module.ts, signup.page.ts and signup.page.html. As described in many of these answers, it is important to import ReactiveFormsModule, etc. into the correct module.ts file and to create the form in ngOnInit() in the correct corresponding .ts file.  If you are adding a form to a single page of the app, the code needs to go in the file structure for that page.

Comment: If one is not using Template Driven approach why do they need to import {FormsModule} ?

Comment: Yep, this did it for me, had to add it to `TestBed.configureTestingModule` ;)

Answer (score 8):

In your code formGroup is missing try this:
`<form [formGroup] = "">`

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very similar to this question and your code looks missing `[formGroup]` as it is mentioned in this question:

[Angular 5: "No provider for ControlContainer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959037/angular-5-no-provider-for-controlcontainer)

If you try its answer, would that work for you?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had forgotten to put `ReactiveFormsModule` to the `imports` section in the corresponding `.spec.ts` file.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar scenario.

Issue is that angular v9 didn't liked @Host() any more.
Fix is removing @Host() from dependency declaration in the constructor.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31539

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Modal for Ionic

Then import this

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'; //imports

to the parent module of the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all the below conditions correctly configured

In app.module.ts

> import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
   ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
```

In app.component.ts

```
userForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      'username': new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
      'password': new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
      'confirm-password': new FormControl(null,Validators.required)
})
```

In **HTML** code

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
......
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue with Angular 9 and I already had `ReactiveFormsModule`  and `FormsModule` imported.

Turns out that `@Host()` decorator is not working with Ivy. Only solution that helped is removing `@Host()` from the dependency declaration in the constructor.

Angular new Rendering engine [Ivy doesn't like @Host() decorator.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31539)