# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project where I want to display a form inside a bootstrap modal. I have added the bootstrap modal as available on their website and trying to add a reactive form in its body. Below is my code:

> .html

```
           ...
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form [formGroup] = "addDataForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Project Type</label>
                <input type = "text" class="form-control" [formControlName] = "pt">
                <label>Fiscal Year (F.Y.)</label>
                <input type="text" class = "form-control" [formControlName] = "fiyr">
                <label>Task Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName] = "td">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          ...
```

> .ts

```
addDataForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit()
{
       this.addDataForm = new FormGroup({
      'pt': new FormControl(null),
      'fiyr': new FormControl(null),
      'td': new FormControl(null),
});
```

I have also imported both of these modules in:

> app.module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
```

I have tried different things after searching quite a bit and still getting this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
```

Comment: Remove the square brackets from the `formControlName` attribute.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the solution mentioned in this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61427097/7671803

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `[formGroup]`, you can do either of the following:

1. `formControlName="pt"` for all form controls
2. `[formControl]="addDataForm.controls.pt"`, note that this would be an issue for nested formGroups.

Comment: I have tried both of these and I am still getting this error.

Comment: You must be missing something then, here's the working example with your code components: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sv6soq-psjthh?file=src/app/button-toggle-appearance-example.html