# Error when creating reactive form in angular

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm getting the following error when creating a reactive form in Angular 10:

No provider for ControlContainer
core.js:4127 ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]

```
HTML Code

    <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="projectName">Project Name</label>
              <input formControlName="projectName" type="text" class="form-control" id="projectName"> 
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
              <input formControlName="mail" type="text" class="form-control" id="mail"> 
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="prjectStatus">Project Status</label>
              <select formControlName="projectStatus" class="form-control" id="prjectStatus">
                <option value="stable">Stable</option>
                <option value="critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="finished">Finished</option>
              </select> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Typescript Code:

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
    
        export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        
          signupForm: FormGroup;
        
          ngOnInit(): void {
        
            this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
              'projectName' : new FormControl(null),
              'email' : new FormControl(null),
              'projectStatus' : new FormControl('critical')
            });
          }
        }
```

Comment: Update your module.ts file and format your error

Comment: You will Find your answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959037/angular-5-no-provider-for-controlcontainer

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `FormsModule` in addition to `ReactiveFormsModule` in the relevant module. (or `app module` if you want it available globally)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `ReactiveFormsModule` to the imports Array of `app.module.ts` & importing `ReactiveFormsModule` from `'@angular/forms'`