# Template Parsing Error "There is no directive with exportAs set to ngModel" in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have created one sample project where i have taken to component one with the name of registration and one with the name of login while validation the registration page giving me the below mentioned error

**While form validation, the error occurs**

```
>Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="email" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" [ERROR ->]#email="ngModel" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
        </div>
```

This is my registration component where i have created one form and trying to validate that form

**registration.component.html**

```
    <form #varSubmit="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(varSubmit)" novalidate>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" required />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          Date of Birth:
          <input type="date" name="dob" />
        </div>
        <div>Gender:
          <input type="radio" value="rbtnMale" name="gender" checked/>
          <label for="rbtnMale">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" value="rbtnFemale" name="gender" />
          <label for="rbtnFemale">Female</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="email" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" #email="ngModel" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="email.pristine || email.valid">Email Shouldnt Empty...!</div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="password" name="cPwd" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" />
          <input type="reset" name="btnReset" />
        </div>
      </form>
```

This is my app.module.ts file where i import the FormsModule

**app.module.ts page**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponentComponent } from './login-component/login-component.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/Forms';
import { UserRegistrationComponent } from './user-registration/user-registration.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponentComponent,
    UserRegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login-component',
        component: LoginComponentComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'user-registration',
        component: UserRegistrationComponent
      },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you import `FormsModule` into your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559296/there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngform)

Comment: Yes i have added FormsModule into my app.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

tell us that we either:

- forgot to import dedicated module
- forgot to add directive to declarations array
- **didn't apply directive on element**

Looking at your code:

```
<input type="email" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" #email="ngModel" 
      [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
```

I noticed that there is no any attribute `ngModel` or property binding `[ngModel]` on this element.

So start with adding `ngModel` attribute.

```
<input type="email" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" #email="ngModel" 
      ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with Angular 11, I was binding input field to template variable (i.e. [(ngModel)]="UserNameSearch") instead of component property since I had same property name as template variable. I changed my component property to camel case and used it to bind and it worked.

**Before**: [(ngModel)]="**U**serNameSearch" (binding to template variable)
[image: Binding property name same as template variable]

**After**: [(ngModel)]="**u**serNameSearch" (binding to component property)

[image]