# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("<div>

Tags: angular, angular7

I already went thru [There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559296/there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngform) but still not able to solve the below error.

Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("<div>
    <form novalidate [ERROR ->]#f=ngForm  [formGroup]="pForm">
        <div class="dxp-input">
            <label class="dxp-input"): ng:///StudentModule/StudentComponent.html@1:21
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<div>
    <form novalidate #f=ngForm  [ERROR ->][formGroup]="pForm">
        <div class="dxp-input">
            <label class="dxp-inputbox-label">"): ng:///StudentModule/StudentModule/StudentComponent.html@1:32
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("gth="0" maxlength="100"

AppModule.java

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TemplateComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

myForm

```
<div>
    <form novalidate #f=ngForm  [formGroup]="pForm">
        <div class="dxp-input">
            <label class="dxp-inputbox-label">
                Program Name
                <span class="dxp-required"><span aria-hidden="true">*</span></span>
            </label>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="" class="input-box" aria-required="true" 
                    autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="program.programName"
                    name="StudentName" [disabled]="isEdit? 'disabled' : null" formControlName="programName"  required>
            </div>
            <div class="dxp-error dxp-required" aria-label="Please select this field" id="errMsg1">
                {{errorStudentName}}
            </div>
        </div>
        ......
        ......
        .....
    </form>
<div>
```

Comment: `#f=ngForm` is not valid, but **why** are you using both reactive and template driven form. Just don't, makes no sense. Choose either ;)

Comment: Using `#f=ngForm`, I am making save Button enable/disable if all fields on the form is populated. What is the way to achieve form validations for required field and custom validation?

Comment: Take a read of https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview there you get introduced to both template driven and reactive forms. If you are using angular 7, aren't you also getting an warning for using both btw?

Comment: Nope, I am not getting warning anywhere