# How to make a html form to angular form

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have created an component called login. I have created a html form login.component.html then I wanted to make this form as Angular form. So I added `<form #loginform="ngForm">` in login.component.html and import `import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms'` in login.component.ts. Can you help me where is the issue?

So when I run the server I get an error said:

```
  ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.html:2:23 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
    
    2     <form #loginform="ngForm">
                            ~~~~~~
    
      src/app/login/login.component.ts:6:16
        6   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
```

login.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

login.component.html:

```html
<div class="container">
    <form #loginform="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ngmodel-and-formcontrols-e0g

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe if you add the FormsModule to the your Module, your problem will be solved or you can create login component by Command ng g c login**

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ngForm. Use angular reactive forms it is better and easier to create and manage.

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

but if you want to continue with the current setup please check this answer

[TypeScript-'s Angular Framework Error - "There is no directive with exportAs set to ngForm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559296/typescript-s-angular-framework-error-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set)

Comment: I imported this import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; but still same error. Do you know how to solve it?