# ngForm or [formGroup] are not known inside a formly wrapper

Tags: angular, forms, directive

I'm using formly as a components generator (not only for forms's inputs generation).
However, i have a wrapper called form, and a type called input.

wrapper:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldWrapper } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'form',
 template: `
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
        <ng-container #fieldComponent></ng-container>
    </form>
 `,
})
export class FormWrapperComponent extends FieldWrapper {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
        console.log(f.value);  // { first: '', last: '' }
        console.log(f.valid);  // false
      }
}
```

input type:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'inputType',
 template: `
 <input type="{{to.type}}" class="{{to.class}}" name="{{to.name}}" ngModel placeholder="{{to.placeholder}}"/>
 `,
})
export class InputComponent extends FieldType {}
```

I tried also:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

But it returns the errors:

```
No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
```

or

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
```

Comment: Have you imported formModule in ngModule?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes I imported it. Is there a way to import it to the formlyModule?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported formModule in ngModule?

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';    
@NgModule({
  imports: [
             BrowserModule,

             FormsModule      //<----------make sure you have added this.
           ],
  ....
})
```

More : [TypeScript-'s Angular Framework Error - "There is no directive with exportAs set to ngForm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559296/typescript-s-angular-framework-error-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set)

Comment: Yes I have import it.